# Is my understanding on this piece of correct?I am getting an output 12 for the below code which is stated as wrong

Tags: codeigniter

The piece of code returns the value "P". Initialized with something blank,I want to understand what does this code produce. I am getting an output as 12 which is not true. `asciiValueof('A')` this is as taken as `065` .

```
p= ""
code = 15
while(code>0)
{
    if (code % 2 == 0)
    {
        p=p+toString(code)
        code-= 1
    }
    else
    {
        code-= 3 * (asciiValueof('A') - 64)
    }
}
\i want to print p\
print(p)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should produce "1284" from the program flow.

About how.
This is what you have as code and p after each iteration

```
   // code =15, p="" 
   //  code =12, p="", substracting 3 from code adding nothing to p
   //  code = 11, p ="12" add code to p, subtracting 1 from code
   //  code = 8, p="12" substracting 3 from code adding nothing to p
  //  code =7   p = "128" add code to p, subtracting 1 from code  
 //  code =4   p ="128" substracting 3 from code adding nothing to p
 //  code = 1  p = "1284" add code to p, subtracting 1 from code
//  code =0, p = "1284" terminate from loop as code is not > 0
```

Comment: Could you please explain how?To understand where i am lacking ?